# creating mysql columns for nested json data

Tags: java, mysql, json

i want to insert json data into mysql please suggest the columns name as i am getting error while inserting json data to databses.

```
[{
  "lat": 48.79001919185189,
  "data": [
    {
      "quantity": 2,
      "power": 20.0,
      "occupied": 0
    },
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "power": 22.0,
      "occupied": 0
    }
  ],
  "lon": 11.37841653121336
},
```

need to know the columns names to be used for this case.

my table has lat,quantity,power,occupied and lon columns as of now but under data there are two more nested 0 and 1.

`java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)`.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: And the entire json.

Comment: sorry the error is :java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: @Filip123go json file [{"lat": 48.79001919185189, "data": [{"quantity": 2, "power": 20.0, "occupied": 0}, {"quantity": 1, "power": 22.0, "occupied": 0}], "lon": 11.37841653121336}, {"lat": 48.78038, "data": [{"quantity": 2, "power": 11.0, "occupied": 0}], "lon": 11.37742000000003}, {"lat": 48.7764, "data": [{"quantity": 2, "power": 22.0, "occupied": 0}, {"quantity": 3, "power": 2.3, "occupied": 0}], "lon": 11.3869}, {"lat": 48.775956251972, "data": [{"quantity": 6, "power": 11.0, "occupied": 0}], "lon": 11.389095187835645},

Comment: That is not a valid json file... You can check your json here : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com . You have to close your json with    "}]" instead you have a ","